# Exclude results using WHERE statement in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a complex query to display some products in different shops. I'm trying to exclude some results but I'm not be able to do it. I have a table looking like this:

```
ProName     ProColor     ProSize      ShopName      ShopAddress
Pro1        col1         10           Shop1         Address1
Pro2        col2         12           Shop2         Address2
Pro3        col3         12           Shop1         Address1
Pro3        col3         12           Shop2         Address2
```

And the query (essential):

```
SELECT Products.ProId, Products.ProName, Products.ProColor, Products.ProSize, Shop.ShopId, Shop.ShopName, Shop.ShopAddress Stock.StockId, Stock.StoProId, Stock.StoShopId
FROM Products, Shop, Stock
WHERE ((Stock.StoProId = Products.ProId) AND (Stock.StoShopId = Shop.ShopId))
```

The above table has 4 columns. When Product and Color and Size are equals, but I have the product in different shops, I only want to show once in the table like this (no matter wich ShopName shows, but only one):

```
ProName     ProColor     ProSize      ShopName      ShopAddress
Pro1        col1         10           Shop1         Address1
Pro2        col2         12           Shop2         Address2
Pro3        col3         12           Shop1         Address1
```

Please, can someone help me?

Comment: This is not complex... but you definitely should think about using joins in your query for a start

Comment: The original table is more complex than this, I only exposed the essence of that.

Comment: You should anyway think about joins...

Answer (score 1):

A simple GROUP BY clause at the end of the request should work

```
GROUP BY Products.ProColor, Products.ProSize
```

but that's a strange query.

Comment: The GROUP BY in ADF / JDeveloper force me to include all the items of the first select...

Comment: are you using a query/read-only view object or entity view objecT?